# How does this recursive function work?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I do not see how this recursive function works:

```
function f(n) { g(n-1) }

function g(n) {
   alert("before: " + n);

   if(n > 0) f(n);

   alert("after: " + n);
}

f(2)​;​
```

I have tried to understand this code works and I saw how "before 1", "before 0", and "after 0" execute but... how does "after 1" come from this?

I see it executing as this... f(2) calls g which subtracts 1 so 'n' becomes 1. Alert("before: " + n) is executed, 1 is greater than 0 so it will recall itself and subtract 1. Alert("before:" + n) is executed once again, 0 is not greater than 0 so it will execute Alert("after:" + n) and the function ends?...

**Edit:** Thank @FlorianMargaine and @Cyrille for helping me understand the logic behind this. =)

Comment: So what is not clear? You seem to be following the logic pretty well.

Comment: How is "after 1" alert called if the function ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after 1` comes from the fact that in Javascript, **parameters are passed by value instead of by reference**. So on the first iteration, calling `if(n > 0) f(n);` which calls `g(n-1)` does NOT decrement `n`. Its value is kept for when `if(n > 0) f(n)` returns, and remains at its value of 1.

Here's a call graph:

```
f(2) calls f(n) with n=2
├─ calls g(n-1), which is g(2-1) = g(1)
│   ├─ g(1) alerts "before: 1"
│   ├─ g(1), n > 0 ==> call f(1)
│   │   ├─ f(1) calls f(n) with n=1, but it's not the same "n"
│   │   │  as we're in another call (see the call tree?)
│   │   │   ├─ calls g(n-1), which is g(1-1) = g(0)
│   │   │   │   ├─ g(0) alerts "before: 0"
│   │   │   │   ├─ n == 0 ==> don't call f(n)
│   │   │   │   └─ g(0) alerts "after: 0"
│   │   └─ and that's all for f(1)
│   └─ g(1) alerts "after: 1"
└─ and that's all
```

Comment: Hmmm it seems like the function would run for an endless cycle if n wasn't decremented.

Comment: No, because `if (n>0) f(n)` calls in turn `g(n-1)`, so basically it won't loop endlessly.

Comment: Really, the keyword here is "by value instead of by reference". Do you know what that means? Not because you're calling f(n-1) means n will change. It will stay here until the sub-routine returns.

Comment: So the function basically creates a new function underneath it which then alerts "before: 0" and "after: 0". After that function finishes executing the function above it destroys it... and now finishes executing itself. This is where the "after: 1" alert comes from.

Comment: Good explanation. I would add a bit about funcalls basics (stacks, call frames), as the OP seems to have problem understanding how parameters and local variables work.

Comment: @W3Geek: exactly. You've just discovered what is called a **call stack**: function calls are stacked one above the other, just like a pile of plates. Cleaning the uppermost plate (returning from the topmost function in the stack) doesn't mean your whole pile of plates will instantly vanish.

Comment: @thg435 Yes I have a small understanding of how they work but call stacks, returning functions in functions, and closure confuse me quite a bit. Cyrille What do you mean by your whole pile of stacks won't instantly vanish?

Comment: You seemed to think that once g(0) was called, g(1) would stop and never alert "after: 1", no?

Answer (score 1):

See the call order:

```
Calls f() with parameter 2
f() calls g() with parameter 2-1 -> 1
g() alerts "before: 1"
since n > 0, g() calls f() with parameter 1 -- and blocks further execution of current g() with parameter 1 - in other words, it goes down in "funception"
f() calls g() with parameter 1-1 -> 0
g() alerts "before: 0"
since n === 0, it skips the if
g() alerts "after: 0"
finally, the blocked execution can resume because the inner function has finished executing, so it alerts "after: 1"
```

It's not really "blocking", it just executes the inner function before executing the rest of the current function.

To clearly understand the logic, just try to follow it by "speaking it".

Comment: To add to this - it finally calls "after 1" after the f(1) returns.

Comment: I still don't understand how after 1 alert is called? :(

Comment: @FlorianMargaine What do you mean by "it doesn't pass the if"? I thought JS skips an if statement if it doesn't result to true?

Comment: @W3Geek yeah, it skips it, just used the wrong word :) I meant "the condition doesn't pass, so the if is skipped"

Comment: Oh haha =) I think I understand a bit better now. So by "funception" the function creates another function under it which results in "before 0" and "after 0". Afterwards the function destroys whats underneath it so it can run and alerts "after 1"? This is very confusing to see without knowing what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Make more sense now? n ≤ 0 is the base case.

```
function g(n) {
   alert("before: " + n);

   if(n > 0) g(n - 1);

   alert("after: " + n);
}

g(2)​;​
```

Comment: No it still doesn't make any sense. I don't see how "after 1" alert is called. =/

Comment: When n = 1 after g(0) is called, alert("after: " + n) is called.

Answer (score 0):

Each function call returns eventually. The code calls `f()`/`g()` recursively, but at some point `n` reaches 0 and `f()` is not called in the `if` statement, thus it alerts `after: 0` and starts returning up the chain of calls, eventually reaching the first stack frame, where `n` is `1`.